# How to reset the Xorg / xserver?

Tags: xorg, xserver

Xserver keeps crashing on my general user account both in Unity 3D and 2D.
It doesn't do it on the guest account.

That's why I want to reset / rollback everything xserver related, hoping this is going to fix it.

Most answers on this involve `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`. However, this does nothing for me (generates no output) and I read in other forums, that it's deprecated.

So, what's the current way to reset all xserver / xorg options; what's the alternative to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`? X crashes during work, not before login or so. And the effect of a crash is, that I get thrown out of the session, not a freeze or machine crash.

Comment: @Jorge Castro The version of Ubuntu is important here, as things have changed. There is no more "gdm" and neither works the dpkg-reconfigure, I believe.

Comment: have you tried resetting xorg.conf? (backup and remove)

Answer (score 13):

If your guest account is not affected this could be a user-specific setting that is causing the problem. Try deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. Actually I don't think it's the monitor settings, as the guest account doesn't crash, even when I configure both monitors ...

Comment: OK, while that was not really it, the idea behind it solved my problem: one-by-one deleting files in ~/.config dir did work for me! :-) @Jorge Castro: if you modify your answer into this direction, I'll mark it "accepted"

Comment: I have no idea what files you deleted, feel free to add all that information in the answer though, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: This helped me resolve some problems with fglrx (AMD CCCLE).

Comment: This helped on Manjaro for a listed but not supported display mode on Huawei Matebook 2020 AMD

Answer (score 9):

The alternative to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` is  `sudo X -configure`

Answer (score 7):

To reconfigure packages that are already installed, you can refer to:

[Ubuntu Manpage: dpkg-reconfigure - reconfigure an already installed package](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html)

**Using the terminal:**

1. If you've got to a blank screen while booting up, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to access the terminal.

   Then, depending on your desktop environment, terminate the X using:

   - For Gnome (Ubuntu): `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop`
   - For KDE (Kubuntu): `sudo /etc/init.d/kdm stop`
   - For Xfce (Xubuntu): `sudo /etc/init.d/xdm stop`
2. For the reconfiguration process:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
   ```

   **Note:** A backup is always recommended before running the configuration, so you can do it using:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
   ```
3. Restart the GUI:

   Again, this depends on the desktop environment, so:

   - For Gnome (Ubuntu): `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start`
   - For KDE (Kubuntu): `sudo /etc/init.d/kdm start`
   - For Xfce (Xubuntu): `sudo /etc/init.d/xdm start`

---

If fail to perform the above steps, one can always edit the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` manually and replace the file contents.

**Refer to:**

- [Binary package “xserver-xorg-core” in ubuntu lucid](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/xserver-xorg-core)
- [examples and default linux configuration files](http://wiki.dennyhalim.com/rc-dot-conf#toc3)

Comment: For `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` I get sudo /etc/init.d/gdm _command not found_ and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` does not do anything for me, as I pointed out in the question. Thx for answering though ...

Comment: @thomas Very strange, but just added the links were you can collect the default contents for the xorg.conf file. Perhaps manually setting the file contents can help you.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 the display manager is _lightdm_, not _gdm_. Why the dpkg-reconfigure doesn't work, I don't know! :-/

Comment: @thomas Perhaps [reinstalling the dpkg](http://people.adams.edu/~cdmiller/posts/Ubuntu-dpkg-recovery/) itself may allow you to use it!

Comment: In my case, after the login screen, the screen was black. The steps outlined in this answer solved it. I had to login through SSH from another computer to enter the commands.

Comment: no such thing in ubuntu 16

Answer (score -2):

After trying all you guys mentioned here I solved the very same problem by setting ownership (and permissions) of .Xauthority and .ICEauthority (located inside: /home/username/ folder) back to my general user.

to check own/perm start tty1 (CTRL+ALT+1) and login, take superuser (sudo su) and:

```
cd /home/username/
ls -a -l
```

in my case .Xauthority wasn't even readable by my general user, so first I had to chmod:

```
chmod 775 .Xauthority
```

then:

```
chown username .Xauthority
chown username .ICEauthority
```

after this, reboot and try to login -- it worked for me.

Another note: I faced this problem after iterative experiments with xorg.conf and NVidia drivers - trying to setup 3 monitors with 2 cards. So, I spent huge amount of time trying to solve the problem playing around xserver and video settings -- while the reason of crash was totally unrelated.

Comment: `chmod 775` on the authority files is the wrong thing to do™