# Can't run in GUI mode in newly installed 14.04

Tags: boot

I had been using Ubuntu 13.04 and I chose the upgrade option from the Ubuntu live CD and chose to keep the installed file as it is. The installation successfully completed with an error message saying `some older packages may have to be reinstalled`. I restarted the computer, but now I can't login to the computer in GUI mode. It gives an error message that it can't find graphics drivers. When I click on the only available button OK, I get the following dialogue box:

[image]

and then when I click the first option I get this one :

[image]
which never restarts anything.

Clicking the second option gives the following:
[image]

and clicking OK gives the same dialogue box recursively.

Third option shows a error log file and fourth option lets me smoothly use the Ubuntu 14.04 in GUI mode and my files are safe in my drive.

So how do I get rid of this problem? I assume graphics drivers come with Ubuntu 14.04 itself.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: AMD graphics card. I have intel 4200U i5 CPU.

Comment: @PrakashGautam Which one exactly? Use _lspci_ in the command line to get the exact spec.

Comment: 00:00.0 VGA compatible controller Haswell-ULU Interated graphics Controller (rev 09)
03:00.0 AMD nee ATI Sun [Radeon HD 8600M Series]

Comment: Same happened to me, just remove graphic drivers, reinstall x.org, lightdm, ubuntu desktop and have fun

Comment: how do I remove graphics drivers when all I get are the error messages mentioned above and can't penetrate into user interface of 14.04?

Comment: so what's the error log file?

Comment: From the CLI, run this command: `dpkg -l | grep fglrx | awk '{ print $3 }'`. This command will print out the version number of the fglrx (ATI) driver that you currently have installed (if any). Additionally, please provide the output of: `modinfo fglrx | grep "^version" | awk '{print $2}'`, which will give use the version of fglrx currently install and being used in the kernel. I have a hunch that update-initramfs may have packaged the wrong version of the driver into the initramfs, leading to graphics problems. Or, perhaps, it's not even installed -- which may give the same results.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep fglrx | awk '{ print $3 }'` gives nothing but  `modinfo fglrx | grep "^version" | awk '{print $2}'` gives `ERROR: Module fglrx not found.`

Comment: What does _/var/log/Xorg.0.log_ say? Your system has both Intel HD4400 graphics and AMD HD8600M. Perhaps fglrx got removed, but xorg.conf is still configured to use it? Try deleting your old xorg.conf as the answer below suggests.

Comment: @Prakash Gautam please provide your aforementioned error log file. Please help us help you.

Comment: I tried to view the file with `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` which shows a long file and I am sorry I don't understand what the information mean!

Comment: You don't help mentioning the size of a file content. But you may help uploading it into a web service where we can read it. Upload it [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and link it in your question-

Comment: I so very much want this question be be reconsidered. I am in a deep trouble as I keep on getting `404 Not found` whenever I try to install new packages. I still  have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem every-time when i try installing ATI graphic card drivers on my hp laptop.

I think your problem is your graphic card drivers supported in 13.04 version are not working in the 14.04 version. so you need to uninstall the graphic drivers.

To uninstall the graphic drivers, boot into recovery mode run as root and try uninstalling your graphic drivers if you installed fglrx then you can try this command

sudo apt-get purge fglrx

and reboot

I hope that works

Comment: Hmm, this seems almost correct except that at the end of this the user is left without a graphics driver -- instead using Vesa which probably won't work out too well. We may need some more information about this in order to properly rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into recovery and remove your `xorg.conf` file, then reboot.

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist in my system.

Answer (score 0):

log into a teminal:

Hold CTRL and ALT and tap F1

login

issue the command

```
sudo X -configure
```

source: [How to reset the Xorg / xserver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159663/how-to-reset-the-xorg-xserver) - top answer at this current time.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 by yours truly. I can verify that the command is recognized and accepted. YMMV (I get display already active which in my case is true)

Comment: Sorry I may be doing some silly error here; when I do CTRL+ALT+F1 I get a console screen; but I can't login. It says incorrect login. I enter <username> and <password> but it says incorrect login. Now I have installed 13.04 back. I may be able to do that from terminal, to prepare for 14.04 installation. Is that possible?

Comment: @PrakashGautam I would prepare for installation by backing up all my data. Once I was sure I had backed up everything I needed I'd wipe the drive and install fresh. Then copy my backed up data onto the system.  Since you've installed 13.04 back this question is no longer relevant to your current situation. It's still a valuable question though. We appreciate you bringing it to our attention as it is likely to help others. I experienced too many problems with both 13.04 and 13.10 to consider using them seriously. 14.04 is so far much more stable for me although I still run 12.04 for benchmarks

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and login.

If you've installed fglrx using apt-get/Software and updates:

```
sudo su
apt-get purge fglrx*
reboot
```

If you've installed fglrx from AMD's website:

```
sudo su
cd /usr/share/ati
bash amd-uninstall.sh
reboot
```

After rebooting, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, login again, and then install open-source drivers:

```
sudo su
apt-add-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers # Optional, gives little performance boost
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx mesa-vdpau-drivers
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
reboot
```

And never install fglrx again.