# Ubuntu won't boot after update from 14.04 to 15.10

Tags: 14.04, boot, updates, 15.10

My ubuntu won't boot after the update to wily wolf. All i get is a blank screen, from which I can switch to tty, can login on those and am able to ping ie google. I've tried looking up this problem but can't find amything besides hints of kernel/gfx deiver related problems. Does anyone know why this happens? Amd more importantly, how can I solve this?

I've tried switching to different drivers with select-prime. The option 'Intel' gives me the boot checklist and nividia just leaves me hanging in the dark.

Comment: Try to run `dmesg` command and post any errors or warnings which occurs there.

Comment: I have had very similar problems. The gdm login wouldn't start but I was able to switch to tty. For me the solution was to switch to lightdm instead of gdm. I tried so switch back to gdm and the result was the same. When it should show graphical login screen everything seems to freeze.

Comment: It says: [Drm: intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder. And also in red 'This pci device is not a vga device'

Comment: *What did you actually do to 'update'?* You can't 'upgrade' from **14.04 LTS** to **15.10** (other than via 14.10, then 15.04). *Any direct 'upgrade' is not a supported (or tested) path.*

Comment: Might be similar problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/456205/cant-run-in-gui-mode-in-newly-installed-14-04

Comment: Well... I'm trying to fresh install ubuntu 15.10 on my current ubuntu partition and it says 'No root file systen is defined'. Is it possible that it's part of the cause as to why Ubuntu 15.10 won't boot up?