# Ubuntu 14.04 keeps on booting into terminal login screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, command-line, login

I have a dual-boot windows and ubuntu system. My pc is and acer aspire desktop computer. For some reason which I can not figure out yet my computer boots into the terminal login screen. I have tried the following commands:

```
$ startx
```

with the following errors:

```
......
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fglrx': Required key not available
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:1:1) found
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fglrx': Required key not available
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

The full `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file is found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23187715/)

I have also deleted the `~/.Xauthority` file, but all it does is recreate it and still boots into the terminal login screen.

Comment: try turning off secure boot in your BIOS

Comment: It says *"Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information."*

Comment: @Zanna I have turned off secure boot in the bios. Now all it does is boot into the gui but when entering my password it simply returns to the gui login screen. So a login loop I guess.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have added the full log file to a pastebin.

Comment: You've seen [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)?

Comment: You might try `sudo X -configure` as mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159663/how-to-reset-the-xorg-xserver and for the login loop: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: @Zanna It seems to have worked to `sudo chown username:username ~/.Xauthority`. Now it boots into a gui login and loads the gui desktop after login. If its ok with you I'll post the solution.

Comment: excellent! please do that :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Zanna suggested, what worked was to boot into the bios and turning off "secure boot". After that it booted into the gui login screen but would go into a login loop after entering my password. I then had to follow the advice on this [page](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/156765) and used `sudo chown username:username ~/.Xauthority`. Now it boots both into the gui login screen as well as logs me into the gui desktop.