# Ubuntu 16.04LTS won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, openvpn, xserver

The computer is a fresh install (5 days old) of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The FS is fully encrypted.

Just before the crash,

- I installed openvpn, added my configuration.
- I wanted to restart NetworkManager, and `sudo restart network-manager` strangely told me it was not authorized (even with the sudo).
- I restarted the machine to see if it would make things better

Since then, upon restart just after typing my filesystem encryption password, I have the following error:

```
Bluetooth: HCIO command 0xaabbccdd tx  timeout

[4:46]
Bluetooth: HCIO: fail to send firmware data (-110)
```

(where 0xaabbccdd is always a different address) and the system won't boot.

The only thing I did related to bluetooth since the last time I rebooted is disabling it from the top-right menu.

When trying to boot with grub (holding shift at startup), the screen stays black forever.

I succesfully accessed my filesystem through a live usb, but I don't really know what I need to do now.

If need be, the errors shown and the last things the Kernel did before dying in the kernel log : https://pastebin.com/T21WdaVn

**EDIT** I've disabled bluetooth driver completely (blackisted the kernel module), and it turns out it's the last error that was printed but it's not the cause of the crash. Now on startup, the screen stays black with a blinking cursor.

**but** the syslog ends with a message saying it can't connect to the serverX, which could clearly be an explanation as to why it's staying with a blinking cursor.

Comment: revert your changes in bluetooth...

Comment: well. What exactly did "unticking Bluetooth in the top right menu" actually changed in then filesystem ?

Comment: Are you on the system now, did you try: `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`?

Comment: I can't run commands, the system won't boot, and blocks during startup. All I can do is access the filesystem from a live usb.

Comment: You can you need to mount your `/dev/sda` then `bind` and you will be able to run commands

Comment: Did you create a custom filesystem or all is on `/dev/sda1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Boot into LiveCD:
2. Do the following to be able to make changes:

   a. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

   b. `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

   c. `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`

   d. `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`

   e. `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`

   f. `sudo chroot /mnt`
3. Then re-enable the bluetooth with:

   ```
   rfkill unblock bluetooth
   ```
4. Restart it with:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
   ```

Note:

I assumed your `root` filesystem is on `/dev/sda1` yours might be elsewhere find with command `sudo fdisk -l`

#### UPDATE

Based on your update try these steps to fix `Xserver`:

1. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` or `sudo X -configure`

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

[How to reset the Xorg / xserver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159663/how-to-reset-the-xorg-xserver)

Comment: systemctl restart bluetooth > "Running in chroot, ignoring request". It seems you can't use systemctl inside a chroot. Good idea though :/

Comment: (I've updated the initial message after a few discoveries)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own answer : actually, the computer was started but the X server wasn't. I can access TTY with `ctrl+alt+f1` and then from a shell, try to repair my X server.

The problem is so different from what was initially described that I'll do a new question if I can't solve it on my own.