# Dual Display not working on GTX 970

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, 19.04

My dual monitors were working perfectly yesterday, but when I turned on my PC today, the monitors will only work when plugged into the motherboard to use the Intel integrated graphics.

I have the Nvidia X Server Settings (nvidia-driver-418) app downloaded (it was auto-detected and auto-installed). Any recommendations?

Note: this is occurring on Ubuntu 19.04.

EDIT: The GPU doesn't show up in Settings > Details > About. The only graphics listed is 'Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)'.

Comment: What does `prime-select query` return?

Comment: I guess the bigger question is what changed between yesterday and today? Can you reboot and select "Advanced Options" on grub menu and select previous kernel? Does it work OK?

Comment: 'prime-select query' returns 'nvidia'.

Comment: Another user reported problems with `418` driver and using `396` driver solved the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135448/pc-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend-mode/1135606?noredirect=1#comment1882986_1135606. I'm using `384` driver with my GTX 970M and have never had a problem.

Comment: How can I permanently change which driver it's using? In Software & Updates, each time I change it, select a new one, click Apply Changes, and restart, it goes back to 'Using X.Org X server'.

Comment: Just folowed the instructions at this link: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu  and now the monior plugged into the GPU will work at the login screen, once I login, it turns off...

Comment: The login screen has user `gdm` configuration. Once you login in your own configuration is used. Your old configuration needs to be reset. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159663/how-to-reset-the-xorg-xserver

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001043sd000085ABbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

$ sudo apt install nvidia-396

$ reboot
```

Comment: All the commands worked, but the second. Doing the last command caused the machine to restart. Now, both screens work while connected to the GPU, but I can't login...  When I enter the password, the screen goes black, and it starts again like if I haven't already entered the password.

Comment: please try  to make your /home/username folder empty

Comment: I was able to login by: at the login screen, clicking Ctrl + Alt + F3, then typing in 'ls -lah', then 'sudo chown username:username .Xauthority'. Now the dual monitors don't work... only the one plugged into the motherboard...