# redetect built-in display

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I have a laptop with a 2nd monitor (via a HDMI output with my nvidia graphic card). I think I messed up the xorg.conf file while configuring the 2nd monitor with nvidia x server because when I restarted the PC, the built-in display is not detected anymore. I checked the backup file and it's empty.

```
sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159663/how-to-reset-the-xorg-xserver) may help you. I don't know if this will re-detect your display but at least it will restore the config files to default.