# Cannot run in framebufffer mode, X11 fails

Tags: 20.04, xorg, framebuffer

Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices, with regard to X-windows.  How do you specify a busID? Occurs in latest LTS release (22.04).

```
[ 263.386] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section. 
[ 263.386] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting" 
[ 263.387] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section. 
[ 263.387] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[ 263.387] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw" 
[ 263.387] (EE) Fatal server error: 
[ 263.387] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices 
[ 263.387] (EE) 
[ 263.387] (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at wiki.x.org
```

Comment: Are there any error messages that can help with debugging? Either printed to the console, the output of `tail -f /var/log/messages`, or `sudo dmesg`?

Comment: [   263.386] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   263.386] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   263.387] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   263.387] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   263.387] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   263.387] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   263.387] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[   263.387] (EE) 
[   263.387] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org

Comment: Edit your original question and add all the info. Sounds like you have a problem with your X config. You could try: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/159663/how-to-reset-the-xorg-xserver might help